# How to check if a string lies in a certain range. (Java)

Tags: java, string

I need to check if a given string is in between a range of strings.

I have two strings in a file (stringA and stringB), my program would allow me to input a name and test if it fits in the range of stringA and stringB.

For example if the file had Adam & William, and I tested John it would return true, as opposed to Zane which falls outside and would return false.

I hope this make sense, and thank you for any help.

Ryan.

Comment: May be you can try this link; [A Reusable Range Implementation
](http://www.cbsolution.net/ontarget/a_reusable_range_implementation)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the String class's `compareTo` method to achieve this functionality, as follows:

```
public boolean inRange(String lowerBound, String upperBound, String input) {
    // (First, be sure to check for null values)
    return input.compareToIgnoreCase(lowerBound) >= 0 && input.compareToIgnoreCase(upperBound) <= 0
}
```

Comment: perfect solution ... thats all I wanted to write but you beat me.

Comment: Wow, brilliant. That was very quick and correct too. Thank you so much Jonathan  : )